# Validate user phone number in CakePHP

Tags: regex, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have created a login system in CakePHP 2.x., in which the user can login from his email address and his phone number. What I want is if a user provides a phone number, for example "123456789" or "+123456789", he can log in into the system. At times now only one task can be achievable through this. If the number in the database is this "123456789", he is not able to login from this "+123456789".

I think I have to apply rules in the model class...

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
  'Authenticate.Cookie' => array(
    'fields' => array(
      'username' => 'email',
      'password' => 'password'
    ),
    'userModel' => 'User',
    'scope' => array('User.active' => 1)
  ),
  'Authenticate.MultiColumn' => array(
    'fields' => array(
      'username' => 'email',
      'password' => 'password'
    ),
    'columns' => array('email', 'mobileNo'),
    'userModel' => 'User',
  )
);
}
```

This is the code to log in from email and mobile number:

**Login Function**

```
public function login() {
  if ($this->Auth->login() || $this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
    $this->redirect('/users/dashboard');
  }else{
    $this->layout='logindefault';
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Account Login');
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
      if ($this->Auth->login() || $this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
        if ($this->Session->check('Auth.User')){
          $this->_setCookie($this->Auth->user('idUser'));
          $this->redirect('/users/dashboard');
        }
      }else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Incorrect Email/Password Combination');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It can be done while checking the condition for phone number, like check for + string and remove it,& check with remaining number ..!!

Comment: @SiddeshBhalke  how ?

Comment: @ HelloSheik Paste your login action code here, let me see how u doing..!

Answer (score 4):

Try This, Before you checking for phone number, just pt this line,

```
  public function login() {


 $this->request->data['User']['mobile']=$this->request->data['User']['mobile'];
   if (strpos($this->request->data['User']['mobile'],'+') !== false) {
         $this->request->data['User']['mobile']=str_replace("+", "",$this->request->data['User']['mobile']);
   }
      $this->requst->data['User']['mobile']=$this->request->data['User']['mobile'];

  if ($this->Auth->login($this->request->data)) {
    $this->redirect('/users/dashboard');
  }else{
    $this->layout='logindefault';
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Account Login');
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
      if ($this->Auth->login() || $this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
        if ($this->Session->check('Auth.User')){
          $this->_setCookie($this->Auth->user('idUser'));
          $this->redirect('/users/dashboard');
        }
      }else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Incorrect Email/Password Combination');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: where do i put your function into my code as i am using auth component which is checking and logging autometically .. can you please put your function into my code .. if u dont mind

Comment: check above thing i have modified, just give proper Model and field name if required..!! do let me know result..!!

Comment: well i do mention here is that i have a inputbox name "email" in which i am getting a mobile number and email ?? so is that your syntax correct for this ?

Comment: try to see what values ur getting in request of data..!!  pr($this->request->data());

Comment: nothing is printing out on the browser .. well i have an email input box if you want to know ..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32468/discussion-between-siddesh-bhalke-and-hellosheikh)